# DataGridView: Style backColor for all individial cells whose value is 0 or 1

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

on MyBase.Load, I connect to an SQL server, get the info I need, and then populate a dataGridView so that it appears as a matrix.

column at index 0 are all my part names and my row heading are all my receiver models.

the matrix is either 1 or 0.

I want to perform: cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red for all cells whose value is 0 and
I want to perform: cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen for all cells whose value is 1

I am trying this so far:

```
`Private Sub dgCorpResults_CurrentCellChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvMatrix.CellFormatting


Try
For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In dgvMatrix.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red
Next  
Catch ex As Exception  
End Try
```

End Sub
`>

just so I can start formulating an idea of how to paint only the cells I need to paint.

Can an expert help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a simple If Then statement.  Assuming you absolutely need the Try statement, you would just need something like this inside of your For Each statement

```
If value=0 Then
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red
Else
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
End If
```

Again, this is making the assumption that you absolutely need the rest, but to me it looks like it could be simplified.

Edit: of course you also need to be able to determine how to get "value".  Which in this case seems to be either value=cell.ToString() or dgvMatrix.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cell(0).Text

Comment: when I use:
dgvMatrix.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).ToString() = 0 I get this error
"Conversion from string "DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Column" to type 'Double' is not valid."

Comment: and also "Conversion from string "DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Column" to type 'Boolean' is not valid." when I use If dgvMatrix.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).ToString() Then...

Comment: Sorry, change .ToString() to .Text